# Get all IDeclaredType-s in current project (for a ReSharper Generator plugin)

Tags: c#, resharper-plugins, resharper-sdk

I'm writing a ReSharper 7.1 Generator plugin and need to get a list of all types declared in the current project (classes, interfaces and structs - `IDeclaredType-s`) for the `GeneratorProviderBase<CSharpGeneratorContext>.Populate` method.

With regular reflection it would be as simple as `Assembly.GetTypes()`, but here it's proven to be quite a challenge. Is there a way to do this?

I've searched high and low, the docs and samples didn't help, then looked through every `*Extensions` and `*Util` class, but couldn't find anything useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with using the cache. It still doesn't seem right, but I expect it to be better than the previous approach. This is still called from a `GeneratorProvider.Populate`:

```
public static IEnumerable<ICSharpTypeDeclaration> GetAllPublicTypeDeclarations(this IPsiModule module)
{
    var declarationCache = module.GetPsiServices().CacheManager.GetDeclarationsCache(module, false, true);
    var declarations = new List<ICSharpTypeDeclaration>();

    foreach (var shortName in declarationCache.GetAllShortNames())
    {
        var declaredElements = declarationCache.GetElementsByShortName(shortName).OfType<ITypeElement>().Where(e => 
        {
            var elementType = e.GetElementType();
            return elementType == CLRDeclaredElementType.CLASS || elementType == CLRDeclaredElementType.INTERFACE || elementType == CLRDeclaredElementType.ENUM;
        });

        foreach (ITypeElement declaredElement in declaredElements)
        {
            var declaration = declaredElement.GetDeclarations().OfType<ICSharpTypeDeclaration>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.GetAccessRights() == AccessRights.PUBLIC);
            if (declaration != null)
            {
                declarations.Add(declaration);
            }
        }
    }

    return declarations;
}
```

Note: The results won't be the same as in the first answer, cause I've changed some restrictions. Also, in both cases, I'm not concerned with partial classes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I needed, but I'm not really sure if it's the right/best approach:

```
[GeneratorElementProvider("MyGeneratorProvider", typeof(CSharpLanguage))]
public class MyGeneratorProvider : GeneratorProviderBase<CSharpGeneratorContext>
{
    public override double Priority
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public override void Populate(CSharpGeneratorContext context)
    {
        var projectCsFiles = GetAllCSharpFilesInProject(context.PsiModule);
        var declarations = projectCsFiles.SelectMany(GetDeclarationsFromCSharpFile).ToList();
        context.ProvidedElements.AddRange(declarations.Select(d => new GeneratorDeclarationElement(d)));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ICSharpFile> GetAllCSharpFilesInProject(IPsiModule projectModule)
    {
        PsiManager psiManager = projectModule.GetPsiServices().PsiManager;
        return projectModule.SourceFiles.SelectMany(f => psiManager.GetPsiFiles<CSharpLanguage>(f).OfType<ICSharpFile>());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ITypeDeclaration> GetDeclarationsFromCSharpFile(ICSharpFile file)
    {
        return file.NamespaceDeclarationNodes.SelectMany(GetDeclarationsFromCSharpNamespace);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ITypeDeclaration> GetDeclarationsFromCSharpNamespace(ICSharpNamespaceDeclaration namespaceDeclaration)
    {
        foreach (var namespaceChild in namespaceDeclaration.Body.Children())
        {
            var classDeclaration = namespaceChild as IClassDeclaration;
            if (classDeclaration != null)
            {
                yield return classDeclaration;
            }
            else
            {
                var childNamespace = namespaceChild as ICSharpNamespaceDeclaration;
                if (childNamespace != null)
                {
                    foreach (var declaration in GetDeclarationsFromCSharpNamespace(childNamespace))
                    {
                        yield return declaration;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any comments or simpler (maybe even built-in) ways of doing this?

Comment: This is, of course, a stripped version, all checks and additional conditions and transformations were removed for brevity.

Comment: This will be very slow, the larger the project gets - you're walking through every file. I don't have 7.1 to hand any more, but you should be able to get this information from ReSharper's [caches](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/4.01+Caches+%28R7%29)

Comment: Thanks for your input Matt! The cache is the first thing I looked at, but it didn't seem too helpful with it's short names: During a debugging session I saw it had 8000+ items for a project containing only 2 cs files. Most of the names were from referenced assemblies, and not classes, so I felt getting those and going through them would be slow. Anyway, I'll give it another try.

Comment: You could take a look at `CacheManager.GetDeclarationsCache` and pass in `DeclarationCacheLibraryScope.NONE`. This should return you an `IDeclarationsCache` that only refers to items in the solution, without including any libraries.

Comment: Aha, don't know how I missed that... Thanks Matt!

Comment: Ok, so I tried using the declaration cache, and it's very useful when I already know e.g. a class name or similar, but it doesn't help much for enumeration. Maybe explaining my use case would help: Given a type kind (class, interface, enum...) I need to return all user declarations of types of the same kind. This is so I could get their properties, CLR names, etc... At some point I might also need to do fuzzy string compare on the names (like Ctrl+T, navigate to type does). Maybe there's some Util or Extensions class I missed?